# Improving sound quality with remote ESD server

Tags: linux, audio, streaming

I'm investigating low-budget ways to get audio from my PC (Ubuntu) to HiFi without wires.
I'm currently testing a setup where Asus WL-500gP wireless router runs ESD daemon and has attached USB soundcard which is then plugged into HiFi.

I'm testing playback on PC with mpg123-esd and Spotify under Wine. The sound is there, latency is unexpectedly low, but I also hear occassional clicks and some distortion from time to time.  I suppose that's because of the low latency and wireless streaming of uncompressed audio--any packet drops, CPU temporarily being busy etc. will cause clicks in sound output.

Is there a way around this problem, increasing latency / buffer size somehow perhaps?

Streaming using shoutcast protocol seems to be a way out but I have feeling that would be a complex and brittle setup.

Answer (score 2):

I tried that around two years ago. I remember I had more luck with `pulseaudio` than with `esound` (which already wasn't actively developed), it is much more configurable (and much more complex!)... still it was barely working (no stream compression and my uplink was not very good). I don't remember the details of that setup now.

Now `pulseaudio` seems to support more protocols (RTP seems promising, as it should handle packet drops properly), so it might (or might not) work better.

Comment: +1 for PulseAudio for this task - but only if PulseAudio is a recent enough release!